# Synergy taking longer than specified to switch screens

Tags: synergy

My setup is as follows.

Synergy Server 1.4.8 on Windows 7 x64

Synergy Client 1.4.8 on OSX 10.6

Server Setting: Switch after waiting 10ms

So, usually this stuff all works well. Also, moving from client to server always seems to work properly. Occasionally though, Moving from Server to client makes me wait 4 seconds before switching my screens. I haven't figured out a reliable way to reset this behavior.

Is anyone aware of this bug? Or, better yet, a fix for it?

Has anyone else noticed this occurring?

I'm gonna try turning up the delay to 20ms, and see if that fixes it by any chance.

Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

This was related to the amount of data in the clipboard. I don't think I had a lot in the clipboard, but when, on OSX, I Command-C'd a single ASCII character, the problem immediately stopped. I solved this by putting the log level on both my server and client into debug1 mode, and left both log tailers open. then, I switched from my Win7 box to my OSX box. I could see the log statements hanging up trying to deal with the clipboard. This is a pretty handy way to debug issues with Server-Client communication in Synergy.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a new alternative, called "ShareMouse". It offers drag & drop of files between computers and also seamless transition between monitors of different size.

Comment: Neither drag & drop or different monitor size support are the focus of this question. Can you attempt to solve the Synergy problem?

Comment: Can't fix known bugs which are well discussed in the Synergy forums. I can only offer a solution to the problem by recomming to use an alternative that just works.

Comment: Well, you could have at least linked to these discussions if you're aware of them. This would have helped.

Comment: @James Sharemouse is useless, it doesn't support Linux.